# Whenever I have output in Visual studio terminal, it adds a bunch of blank lines after my output

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever my VSCode outputs anything to the terminal, even something simple like "Hello World", it appends about 500 blank lines after the output

I have no idea why this happens, but it's new and I didn't make any changes to my settings or otherwise. I looked over my settings in VScode but I didnt see anything that could be related.

Even something as simple as -> "fmt.Println("Hello world")" displays this error.

The problem appears to be related to VS code, it has nothing to do with the actual code being run...

I expect the output to be what the output should be, but instead its whatever the output should be plus about 500 lines of blank text.

Here's an example of what this issue looks like:

[image]